# Unit Testing in CRUD operation in entity frame work in mvc4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to study entity framework in mvc4. I created a project in EF with CRUD operations. Now I want to unit test this (mainly dependency injection). I googled many sites, and tried to do the mock testing method,

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/447988/How-to-Mock-Test-an-Entity-Framework-Model-First-P
```

but it did not work. Actually what is the best method for unit testing an EF? Creating a class for test or create a test project. This is my crud operation code, how can I unit test this, please help me.

Member.cs

```
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public int MemID {get;set;}

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Member Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string MemName { get; set; }

}
```

MemberController

```
 public class MemberController : Controller
 {
    private SampleDataContext db = new SampleDataContext();

    //
    // GET: /Member/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Members.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Member/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Member member = db.Members.Find(id);
        if (member == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(member);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Member/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Member/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Member member)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Members.Add(member);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(member);
      }

    //
    // GET: /Member/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Member member = db.Members.Find(id);
        if (member == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(member);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Member/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Member member)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(member);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Member/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        Member member = db.Members.Find(id);
        if (member == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(member);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Member/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Member member = db.Members.Find(id);
        db.Members.Remove(member);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can test the code by various types of testing. The easiest way to add the class library and test the Code. The another way,you can use NUnit to test it. For that purpose,you have to add certain  dll files to work with NUnit.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive about what would you like to test here ?

Comment: @Dawid: i just want test each crud operation and know how to test is worked in EF

Comment: @siddhesh : can you please tell how it will do, or please suggest a tutorial, i am try it many ways

Comment: You can refer:[link] (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/unit-testing-in-mvc-4-using-entity-framework/)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, most people I know agree that UnitTesting is about testing under isolation. Your proposed tests would test your Controller, your Model and your Persistance layer (as well as any Business Logic you have).

Secondly, given that Databases are ALL about STATE, and UnitTesting should be stateless...this would again be difficult.

However...luckily for you...I've been thinking about how to create stateless integration tests using SQL Server Compact and the `DropDatabaseAlways<T>` database initializer.

The trick here is to setup your test projects to use a SQL Server CE connection string, and inject `DropDatabaseAlways` as your initializer.

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    public FooContext(IDbInitializer<T> init = null, bool forceInit = false)
    {
        if(init != null)
            Database.SetInitializer(init);
        if(forceInit)
            Database.Init(true);
    }
}
```